# Different visualization for hierarchical clustering of dendrogram

Tags: r, data-visualization, hierarchical-data, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I would like to have visualization of hierarchical clustering with shapes one inside the other. Brightness level represents level of hierarchy.
Let me show you my idea with an example:

```
# Clustering small proportion of iris data   
clusters <- hclust(dist(iris[20:28, 3:4]), method = 'average')
# Visualizing the result as a dendogram    
plot(clusters)
```

[image]

Now we can convert the dendrogram as below. 
[image]

Is there any R package that can produce something similar?

Comment: Do you know if there is any special name for the graph I asked?

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer. You can use `clusplot` from the `cluster` package to get some way in that direction. You could probably improve on this by changing the source of `clusplot` (type `getAnywhere(clusplot.default)` to get the source). But it is probably some work to get your bubbles to not overlap. Anyway, here's the plot you get from `clusplot`. It may also be of interest to look at the individual plots one at a time instead of showing them all together.

```
# use sample data
df <- iris[20:28, 3:4]
# calculate hierarchical clustering
hfit <- hclust(dist(df), method = 'average')
# plot dendogram
plot(hfit)
# use clusplot at all possible cutoffs and show on top of each other.
library(cluster)
clusplot(df, cutree(hfit, 1), lines = 0)
for (i in 2:nrow(df)){
  clusplot(df, cutree(hfit, i), lines = 0, add = TRUE)
}
```

[image]